# What does "To" mean in a newspaper headline?

Tags: meaning, titles, headline-english

What does *to* mean in a newspaper headline, for example:

> Airline XY to cut cost of pilots' wages

Is it a shorter form of "Is going to" or "Is planning to"?

Comment: +1: I asked myself this question a lot when I started learning english.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Normally it can be interpreted as "is going to" or "has decided to". In headlines, that construction usually indicates that something will happen; a decision has been made.

There is a construction "Airline XY is to cut costs" which means the same thing. All the headline subeditor has done is to remove the verb "is" (as they often do).